# Increment not counting properly

Tags: java

my increment and exit statement aren't displaying properly. This project is for a class and I am to create a java program that prompts a user for input and and stores the largest number input and the amount of times it was input. My program isn't counting properly it doesn't count the first number entered into the increment.

When a 0 is typed in first the program is supposed to print out

```
Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: 0
No numbers are entered except 0
```

but it keep printing the count along with it.

```
Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: 0
No numbers are entered except 0
The maximum number is 0
The count for the max number is 1
```

Code:

```
int number, max=0, count =1;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//collecting user information
System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
number = input.nextInt();
if (number ==0){
    System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
}
while(number !=0){
    System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
    number = input.nextInt();

    if (number > max){
        max = number;
    }
    else if(number == max){
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println("The maximum number is " +max);
System.out.println("The count for the max number is " +count);
```

Comment: Remove the rows just before the while loop, they make no sense. You need to initialise `number` to a negative value also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to explain properly in a comment

```
int number = -1, max = 0, count = 1;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int askedCount = 0;

while(true){
    System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
    number = input.nextInt();
    askedCount++;

    if (number == 0) {
        break;
    }

    if (number > max){
        max = number;
    } else if(number == max){
        count++;
    } 
}

if (askedCount <= 1) {
    System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
} else {
    System.out.println("The maximum number is " + max);
    System.out.println("The count for the max number is " + count);
}
```

Comment: We are required to have a specific output statement in the situation that the first number entered is 0 and the statement is supposed to read "No numbers are entered except 0" with out including the max or count. 

I can't seem to get the statement to output without it printing the count and max?

Comment: @waffleandbacon I added a new variable to keep a total count, changed the loop a little and then used that counter afterwards to check what to print.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of your comment on Joakim's (original) post, it sounds like you want the second part in an else statement to only happen when your number is not 0.

```
 int number=0, max=0, count =1;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //collecting user information
        System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
        number = input.nextInt();
        if (number ==0){
            System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
        }
    else{
        while(number !=0){
            System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
            number = input.nextInt();

            if (number > max){
                max = number;
            }
            else if(number == max){
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The maximum number is " +max);
        System.out.println("The count for the max number is " +count);
    }
```